# Why am I getting the ClassNotFoundException while starting my tomcat server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a sourceWeb project on the tomcat server and in web library I see a commons-dbcp.jar file too! Then why does this say

```
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
    Aug 29, 2012 2:33:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
    SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\sourceInputWeb does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
```

EDIT::: I see tomcat also has a dbcp jar and it is versioned 1.5 the one which is in the web library of my project is versioned 1.1 .. However I have mentioned it to load like this. Have not included all the parameters but if you look the classname is fully qualified so this version mismatch shouldn't matter correct ?

```
<Resource name="jdbc/CodesDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" auth="Container"/>
```

Comment: did u copy + paste the config file, sometimes the problem is dubious newline characters, I am not sure where did I read but today only I has the same problem which got sorted out by removing new line character and manually formatting the config metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add `commons-dbcp-1.1.jar` and `commons-pool-1.1.jar` to your classpath.

Check this: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

Comment: But it exists under WebApp libraries of my web project so I'm thinking it must already be on classpath.